# Getting a specific value of JSON data

Tags: python, json, parsing

I'm getting a JSON data from RESTCONF HTTPS request, using the following code

```
https_request = 'https://' + host + '/restconf/data/' + operation
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/yang-data+json', 'Accept': 'application/yang-data+json'}
r = requests.get(https_request, auth=(user, password), headers=headers, verify=False)
print r.json()
```

The data I got is the following:

```
{
    "Cisco-IOS-XE-segment-routing:ipv4": {
        "prefixes": [
            {
                "ipprefix": "1.1.1.1/32",
                "index": {
                    "range-start": 333,
                    "range": 1
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Basically, I want to return the field's `"range-start"` value which is `333`. I tried the following but it did not work.

```
for element in r: 
    id = element['range-start'] 
    print(id)
```

Is there anyway to get that value?

Comment: `r.json()['Cisco-IOS-XE-segment-routing:ipv4']['prefixes'][0]['index']['range-start']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Python Console:

```
>>> import json
... data = json.loads('{"Cisco-IOS-XE-segment-routing:ipv4": {"prefixes": [{"ipprefix": "1.1.1.1/32", "index": {"range-start": 333, "range": 1}}]}}')
... print(data['Cisco-IOS-XE-segment-routing:ipv4']['prefixes'][0]['index']['range-start'])
333

>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to start at the beginning of the JSON and work your way to the key you want. To do this you need to start at `Cisco-IOS-XE-segment-routing:ipv4`.

```
prefixes = r.json()["Cisco-IOS-XE-segment-routing:ipv4"]["prefixes"]
id = prefixes[0]["index"]["range-start"]
```

If there are multiple prefixes you can loop over them and access each `range-start`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are looping over elements, I would suggest this approach using a helper function:

```py
def get_id(element):
    prefixes = r.json()["Cisco-IOS-XE-segment-routing:ipv4"]["prefixes"]
    id = prefixes[0]["index"]["range-start"]
    return id
```

Then you can do, as in your question:

```py
for element in r:
    id = get_id(element)
    print(id)
```